# How Can I prevent Microsoft office from displaying local hyperlink warnings

Tags: microsoft-office, security-warning

I am running windows 10 and Microsoft Office 2013. I have created many hyperlinks in a Microsoft Access 2013 database to my MP3 files on an external hard drive. The problem is that I always get this message:

> Opening e:\folder1\folder2\file
>
> Some files can contain viruses or otherwise be harmful to your computer.
>   It is important to be certain that this file is from a trustworthy source. 
>   Would you like to open this file?

I do not want to see this message every time I click a hyperlink to a file that I created. I think I am a trustworthy source on my own computer. I have tried adding the drive as a trusted location.

I have tried creating a registry entry: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Security`

With a **DWORD=DisableHyperlinkWarning** and set value to 1.

Nothing has worked for me. Does anyone have any other ideas? It is very annoying.